# Forcing homogeneous output in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, homogenous-transformation

As part of an assignment related to graphics, I have to solve the simple equation Ax=b. In this equation, A is a known 2x3 matrix, b is a known 2x1 vector, and x is the unknown 3x1 vector, which has to be homogeneous.

Now, I know of the standard MATLAB solution x = A\b; However, this does not force x to be homogeneous. Is there a way I can force the third element of x to be 1?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions (there should be a plane that satisfies the system), so can you not find the point on this plane such at z == 1?

Comment: That would be a great solution, but I don't know of a way to do this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the third element of x to be 1, add an equation that says "x<sub>3</sub>=1". That is, add row `[0 0 1]`  to the matrix and corresponding entry `1` to the vector `b`. Like this:

```
x = [A; 0 0 1] \ [b; 1]
```

#### Example

```
A = [1 2 4; 3 4 5];
b = [6; 7];
```

Simply entering `A\b` returns `[-0.2857; 0; 1.5714]`.

But `[A; 0 0 1] \ [b; 1]`  returns `[-2; 2; 1]`.